# groupByRowLabel doesn't work on Google Timeline

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

Currently, My **timeline Chart** looks like this

[image]

but I want to **put all bars which is the same country on one row**

and I already set

> timeline:{groupByRowLabel:true}

in  options but it doesn't work

My **data** from google sheet looks like this

[image]

*My full code below*

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js'></script>
  <script>
    google.charts.load('current', {
      packages: ["timeline"]
    });

    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

    var data1;

    function handleQueryResponseTR1(response1) {
      if (response1.isError()) {
        alert('Error in query: ' + response1.getMessage() + ' ' + response1.getDetailedMessage());
        return;
      }
      data1 = response1.getDataTable();
      var view1 = new google.visualization.DataView(data1);
      view1.setColumns([{
        type: 'string',
        id: 'Country',
        calc: function(dt, row) {
          return dt.getFormattedValue(row, 0)
        }
      }, 1, 3, 4]);
      var chart1 = new google.visualization.Timeline(document.getElementById('colormap1'));

      var options1 = {

        width: 800,
        height: 1600,
        timeline: {
          groupByRowLabel: true
        }
}
      

      chart1.draw(view1, options1);

    }


    function drawRegionsMap() {

      var query1 = new google.visualization.Query("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sOyYwL51uWTd7Pv4Sp_bKdxWmH-g6QA2SDHhw93_2s8/edit?usp=sharing");
      query1.send(handleQueryResponseTR1);
}
</script>

      <div id='colormap1'> </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have done is absolutely correct. there is nothing to be added in your code.

```
timeline:{groupByRowLabel:true}
```

this will give your labels in same row.

But the problem here is the dataset that ur giving.
All the labels for country(in ur case) will come in same row if and only if date of labels are not overlapping.

say for example, in ur case.

```
Albania WEEE 7/20/2000   6/6/2017  
Albania Batteries 7/20/2015 6/5/2017
```

See the above dates (end time of WEEE and start time of Batteries) are overlapiing.

if the dates are like

```
Albania WEEE 7/20/2000  6/6/2016
Albania Batteries 6/6/2016 6/5/2017
```

check this dates. with this data set ur labels will come in the same row.